# Apache auth_kerb_module on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, kerberos, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to install the Kerberos module in Apache on Windows.

I have copied the file auth_kerb_mod.so to apache/modules/ and I have modified the conf/httpd.conf with LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/auth_kerb_mod.so

But I can't start the Apache service. Apache doesn't find the Kerberos module.

Can you help me ?